# Relocate dependencies from index.html to package.json

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap, package.json

I want to remove my

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
```

dependencies that are related with bootstrap from my index.html file and **implement them on package.json file with installing through npm.**

I installed them and delete those links **but** now bootstrap skills don't recognize and buttons and others don't work.

There is an example for better understanding →

```
    class NavbarToBeConnected extends React.Component {
        componentWillUnmount() {
            this.setState = (state, callback) => {
              return;
            };
        }
    
        render() {
    
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <div hidden={this.props.isDrawModeActivated} className="pos-f-t custom-navbar">
                        <nav className={`navbar ${STYLE_LAYERS[this.props.selectedStyleLayerId].ICON_NB_COLOR_CLASS}`}>
                            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                        </nav>
                        <div className="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
                            <div className="bg-dark p-4 adjust-width adjust-height" style={{height: 'auto', minHeight:520, maxHeight: 600, overflowX: 'hidden', scrollbarWidth: 'thin'}}>
                                <NavbarButton1
                                mapboxRef={this.props.mapboxRef}
                                />
                                <NavbarButton2
                                mapboxRef={this.props.mapboxRef}
                                />
                                <NavbarButton3
                                isDropzoneSet = {this.props.isDropzoneSet}
                                dropzoneOpen = {this.props.dropzoneOpen}
                                />
                                <NavbarButton4
                                mapboxRef={this.props.mapboxRef}
                                />
                                <Accordion 
                                mapboxRef={this.props.mapboxRef}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                    <Modal1
                    mapboxRef={this.props.mapboxRef}
                    />
                    <Modal2
                    mapboxRef={this.props.mapboxRef}
                    />
                    <Modal3
                    mapboxRef={this.props.mapboxRef}
                    />
                    <Modal4
                    mapboxRef={this.props.mapboxRef}
                    />
                </React.Fragment>
            )
    
        }
    }
```

Even though I added import;

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
```

the navigation bar button doesn't work.

What should I do, what is the way to carry dependencies from index.html to package.json as package. ??

Answer (score 0):

### **Try to import these at the `root component` of your app:**

**Run**

```
npm i jquery
npm i bootstrap
```

**Then import them at the root component:**

```
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work and I couldn't see any diff between that and even jquery doesn't recognize from IDE because its' not using anywhere. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: May I have access to your repository?

Comment: the problem is a part of my task that is assigned by company that I am working as intern. They are not using open repo like github etc.

Comment: But I can help you on other way. What is the you couldn't find out?

Comment: I've updated my answer, try again with that one? Also here is one of my repo where I used bootstrap. Try to get a reference there. https://github.com/thinhlesdev/react_component_builder

Comment: Nope, also that didn't change anything either.

Comment: Try to get a reference from my repo, see if you miss anything.